# Magento module un-install

Tags: magento

Is there any feature in magento for un-installing modules?

Im referring to those modules in particular which modify the db. So uninstalling actually consists of removing the module files and cleaning up the db behind itself.

1. Automatic uninstall from admin area
2. Uninstall hooks that modules can observer

Answer (score 1):

**There is no uninstall or rollback mechanism in Magento.** The informally-accepted rollback process is to perform the rollback operation in an upgrade script. The de facto uninstall practice is to provide a removal script to be run on the database after the module files have been deleted.

There has been stub code in place for rollback & uninstall operations in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_getModifySqlFiles()` [since version 1.0](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.0/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php), but it has [yet to be implemented as of 1.7.0.1](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L663).

Answer (score 0):

You can run an uninstall via the Magento Connect manager, removing the database files is relatively simple as well. You may need to take a look at the config.xml and mysql4-install-#.#.#.php sql install script. You can find the table names there and the install entry in the core_resource table.

Comment: Paramount are entity attributes which specify custom backend, frontend, and source models though, something which isn't easily gleaned from install/upgrade scripts.